# A long sentence about a car

Tags: construction

I realize this is OK grammatically, and it even makes sense eventually, but what would you call this style/construction, and how could it be fixed to be more digestible? Is it a run-on sentence, or is it just poorly arranged?

> It's to get kind of a little push maybe from being a long sedan with a front engine that makes me have to wait to get the car turned and pointed toward the apex and then roll into the power.

(From Car and Driver online, reporting on a test drive of a new model)

Comment: Ok grammatically?

Comment: An example of circumlocution, perhaps? How about verbosity? How about just plain poor style? Don

Comment: It may be syntactically all right (especially if you add commas as in egrunin’s answer), but it makes about as much sense to me as “Colourless green ideas sleep furiously”. How can getting a little push make someone be forced to wait to get their car turned around? And why is this same person apparently a long sedan with a front engine?

Comment: I'd call it simply *discursive*: a transcription of discourse (I expect you wouldn't have noticed how rambling it is if you'd heard it rather than read it; our ears are much more forgiving than our eyes).

Comment: Could you put a link to the source?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It's lacking the previous sentence. The *it* there is referential not a dummy subject (this sentence does not involve an extraposition). The *it*, as far as I can tell refers to some understeer which seems to have been deliberately engineered into the car. Best puncutation here would just be a hyphen between *push* and *maybe*

Comment: @Araucaria I still don't understand what exactly it is that makes the writer have to wait to get the car “turned and pointed toward the apex and then roll into the power” (a phrase I don't really understand, either—but then I know bugger-all about cars, so that may just be me being mechanically challenged).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, quite. If you see my deleted post below, you'll understand!

Comment: Oops.. It's from Motor Trend, not Car & Driver.  And that sentence apparently didn't make it into the final article (2015 Best Driver's Car)— I think I can guess why.

Answer (score 2):

Commas might help...though I'm not sure I've understood the bizarre sentence, and thus may have misplaced them:

> It's to get kind of a little push, maybe from being a long sedan with
>   a front engine, that makes me have to wait to get the car turned and
>   pointed toward the apex, and then roll into the power.

Comment: +1 Good job on turning stream of consciousness into humanspeak.

Comment: @bib ***stream of consciousness***: you nailed it. Post that as an answer and you're guaranteed this man's vote.

Answer (score 1):

The phrasing sounds like *[stream of consciousness](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/stream-of-consciousness)*.

> A literary style in which a character’s thoughts, feelings, and reactions are depicted in a continuous flow uninterrupted by objective description or conventional dialogue.

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

And @egrunin does a good job of making it more understandable with punctuation.

Comment: As promised. If I had a checkmark, I'd award that, too :)